# How can I close/revert the call to openURL method

Tags: ios, url-scheme, openurl

When the app gets opened by a URL scheme(for the first time, when app is not even in background), the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the app will get called and we can get the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` from the dictionary `launchOptions`.

I tried to return NO in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but it didn't made any difference.

What I am trying to do is to close the app when there is something wrong with the params in the url , and this url is the url that opens the app.

Let's say the url `myapp://&param1=2&param2=2` opens my app.

In the app delegate, I check for the valid params. If the param values are wrong, I don't want the `URL` to open my app. I want to suspend that action and go back to where I came from.

I tried returing `NO` in both `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and in `openURL` but none gave me what I want.

```
if (![self checkURL:launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]]) {
        DLog(@"Don't launch the app/close the app");
        return NO;
    }
```

Is there a way to close the app(or atleast make the app to go background) if the url is invalid ?

Comment: You should just display an error message in that case.  You can't prevent your app from opening or force it to close and even if you could it would be incredibly confusing to the user.

Comment: I thought showing a pop up to user about the situation and dismiss that pop up and then dismiss the app.Seems like its not possible to do like the way I want.  I wonder why apple didn't provide a way to closeURL just like openURL method.

Answer (score 2):

Closing the app programmatically is technically a violation of Apple's Human Interface Guidelines ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html)). The official reasoning:

> Never quit an iOS app programmatically. People tend to interpret this as a crash. If something prevents your app from functioning as intended, you need to tell users about the situation and explain what they can do about it. Here are two good ways to do this:
>
> 1. **If all app features are unavailable**, display a screen that describes the situation and suggests a correction. The information gives feedback to users and reassures them that there’s nothing wrong with your app. It also puts users in control, letting them decide whether they want to take corrective action and continue using your app or switch to another app.
> 2. **If only some app features are unavailable**, display either a screen or an alert when people try to use the feature. Otherwise, people should be able to use the rest of the app. If you decide to use an alert, be sure to display it only when people try to access the feature that isn’t functioning.

Sounds like you might need to offer some sort of error, and then let the user take action on their own. If you know with certainty where the user originated (or can find out via a URL parameter passed in) then you might be able to offer some sort of automatic routing back into that other app.

Comment: so its like a double routing ? FIrst routing is like from safari to app, and then if my condiiton fails, then route to safari manually again. Is that what you suggest ?

Comment: I think that's what's you would have to do, yes. It would be similar to what Facebook does with their authentication system...it flashes up for a moment and then disappears if already authorized.